Switch Kubernetes cert-manager installation from static manifests to helm without losing existing certificates
We originally installed cert-manager using static manifests. We now need to customise settings (webhook timeout, see digitalocean/clusterlint#167), so I'm thinking the best option is to migrate to a helm installation, but I'm not sure how best to do this and some help would be very much appreciated.
I've read the uninstall instructions, but don't wish to remove certificates or (cluster/) issuers. Can I skip that removal step, as I know I'll be reinstalling with Helm moments later, or do I need to follow a different process?
Any help would be amazing. Thank you 

This might not be perfect for some reason that I'm yet to be aware of, but this seemingly worked perfectly for me…

Upgrade to the latest version, e.g. kubectl apply -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/vX.Y.Z/cert-manager.yaml
Uninstall with kubectl, e.g. kubectl delete -f https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/releases/download/vX.Y.Z/cert-manager.yaml (don't cleanup cert-manager resources first)
Reinstall with Helm (see here)

If any issues come out of the woodwork, I'll let you know, but this does seem to be working fine and has been done in production now.
